# What is the right way to set predetermined column widths with tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I was just wondering about this, because I went over the [`tabularx` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf) and I couldn't find an answer.

So, there are several questions going on here:

1. Is it better to use a proportion of the size of an `X` column or is better to use a defined length (e.g.: 13mm) for column widths in `tabularx` environment?
2. Is question 1) even possible?  Could you predefine the width of an `X` column by length units? (I guess it could be set also using a `p` column, but I don't know if this actually causes any change or just messes things up).
3. What's the advantage of using `hsize` over, let's say, the total width of the table?
4. What is the right approach when dealing with a mixture of fixed-width columns and `X` columns?

Comment: If you use `0.` instead of `0)`, you’ll get the list formatting.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, thanks! I'm still learning markup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It depends what you want
2. It is certainly possible to ask the question. (Just use a `p` column if you want specified width)
3. `\hsize` works.
4. Use `p` `m` `b` for fixed width columns, and use  `c` `l` `r` or `X` in columns without a pre-specified width.

Or you could use `tabulary` (which is easier to use really).