# Extra space between columns (fixed/predefined width and X) in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

This is a follow-up question of: [What is the right way to set predetermined column widths with tabularx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114788/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-predetermined-column-widths-with-tabularx?noredirect=1#114793)

As seen in the code below,

```
\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{table}\tiny
\centering
\caption{Summary of Elders' Fall Assessment Articles tabularx}
\label{tab:FallRiskAssessmentArticles}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright}p{15mm}>{\centering}p{13mm}>{\centering}p{10mm}<{\centering\arraybackslash}XYYYYYY}

\toprule

\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Sensor} & \textbf{Placement} & \textbf{Subject \newline count (M:F)} & \textbf{Movement} & \textbf{Signal Processing} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Dis\-ad\-van\-tages} & \textbf{Outcome} & \textbf{Reference Measure} \\    
\midrule

\noindent\citet{najafi_measurement_2002}&
Gyroscope&
Chest&
11 (5:6)&
STS transitions& 
Wavelet transform& 
Uses normal postural transition.  Can be used during ADL&
Gyroscope must be worn on chest& 
Extracted parameters show significant differences between high/low risk groups&
Fall risk using Tinetti tests, cognitive and vision tests, plus history of falls\\    
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{landscape}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Where you can see there is a big space between column 4 and 5.  Why if I'm using predefined widths I get this result? How do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

David Carlisle suggested to use `tabulary` package, but it seems there is a compatibility issue with `arydshln`, which is one of the packages I'm loading.

Comment: Calling David Carlisle! There's been a spill in aisle, I mean column, 4.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA

Comment: Your fourth column is as wide as the ones following it, because you just required so, specifying it as `X`.

Comment: @egreg So how can I "draw a line" where to stop them doing this?  I just want the first four forced to a certain width and the rest to be free to be set as appropriate by any other algorithm

Comment: Specify also the fourth column as `p`, if you don't want it to be automatically sized.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> ...\midrule \par \noindent \citet 
please  always post _complete_ documents showing all packages used.

Comment: unless you are a publisher automatically generating thousands of tables from some XML database, really I wouldn't use `tabularx` or `tabulary`. Just use `tabular` and use `c` columns or `p` columns of a width that you choose. It is your data you can do a much better job of deciding how much space to allocate to each column.

Comment: Please read [these instructions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that#answer-3225) and make a more reasonable example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X` columns are just `p` columns which are all set to the same width, where the width is calculated to make the total table width the specified size. So all the X and Y columns in your table are the same width,

All the entries in that column are single line so you could just use `c` so the column is set to the natural width of its content.

Or use `\tabulary` instead of `tabularx` The algorithm used there *does* allocate wider columns to columns with more data.

[image]

A **complete** document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape,tabulary,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{table}\tiny
\centering
\caption{Summary of Elders' Fall Assessment Articles tabularx}
\label{tab:FallRiskAssessmentArticles}


\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{10}{C}}

\toprule

\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Sensor} & \textbf{Placement} & \textbf{Subject \newline count (M:F)} & \textbf{Movement} & \textbf{Signal Processing} & \textbf{Advantages} & \textbf{Dis\-ad\-van\-tages} & \textbf{Outcome} & \textbf{Reference Measure} \\    
\midrule

\noindent citet{najaf2002}&
Gyroscope&
Chest&
11 (5:6)&
STS transitions& 
Wavelet transform& 
Uses normal postural transition.  Can be used during ADL&
Gyroscope must be worn on chest& 
Extracted parameters show significant differences between high/low risk groups&
Fall risk using Tinetti tests, cognitive and vision tests, plus history of falls\\    
\bottomrule

\end{tabulary}

\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having some kind of conflict with `tabulary`, it gives me a lot of errors.  I'm loading these "table packages" (in order of appearance): `multirow`, `array`, `tabularx`, `longtable`, `arydshln`, `float`, `adjustbox`, `tabulary`, `booktabs`.  Are there any known compatibility issues?

Comment: @MarioS.E. As always a question with a _complete_ small document showing the problem is more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: I know, I just don't want create a mess by posting a huge list of packages I'm using... but well, I'll copy it on the question

Comment: @MarioS.E. don't post a huge list delete all unused packages and text that uses them (eg `\citet` grrrrr) while still showing the error. That is what anyone trying to answer has to do it is better if you do it.

Comment: I found the guilty package! it is `arydshln`